# Cancelling a d3 node operation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is probably a newbie question, but it has me stumped...  Using D3 to build a collapsible tree.  Most nodes have one line of text, except for one specific type of node, which will have 2 lines.  For my dataset, I always have data for line1, and then all nodes have a field for line2, but it is empty/null for nearly all nodes.  I would like to say "only add a text element if the d.LINE2 data is not null", however d is NOT defined until I am already within the text append operation.  So it looks like I have to start the operation, to get access to d, and then cancel. How do I cancel the append text, if d.LINE2 is null?  Code will help explain this... the first line is causing my issue, because d is not defined, and I understand that.  So how do I code this so that if d.LINE2 is null, then don't do this operation?

```
// if (d.LINE2 !== null) {
  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) {return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
   .attr("dy", "3.6em")
   .attr("fill", "#777")
   .style("font-size", "10px")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {  return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.LINE2; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1)
   .style("fill", "blue");
 //  };
```

Comment: You can filter a selection: `nodeEnter.filter(function(d) { return d.LINE2 != null; }).append(...`

Comment: That did it!  Post as answer and I will accept.